# [Vue + FormKit]: Load Asynchronous Data into a Schema Generated Form

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vuejs3, formkit

**TL;DR**
Is there a way to load asynchronous data into `<FormKitSchema>`?

I'm trying to fetch async data and load it into a FormKit form generated from a JSON schema (`<FormKitSchema>`). I can't seem to find an example and I've tried several ways to do it, but haven't had any luck.

I understand the `value` property on an `input` element will only ever be used when initially rendered, which is cool. However, I can't seem to fetch the data first and then conditionally load the `<FormKitSchema>` afterwards (using `v-if` did nothing to help). It appears the rendering must be executed with the initial component loading or nothing shows up.

Example: `formComponent.vue` (`<FormComponent>`)

```
<template>
  <FormKitSchema :schema="schema" :data="asyncData"/>
</template>

<script setup>
import {reactive, ref} from 'vue';

const getData = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {    
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({name: "How do I get this into the form???"})
    }, 1500)
  })
};

const asyncData = reactive({
  userData: await getData(), // Using 'await' here seems to prevent the form from ever loading
  submit: async (formData, node) => {
    console.log("submit: ", {formData, node});
  }
})

const schema = [
  {
    $cmp: 'FormKit',
    props: {
      type: 'form',
      id: 'form',
      onSubmit: '$submit',
      plugins: '$plugins',
      actions: false,
    },
    children: [
      {
        $formkit: 'text',
        name: 'fullname',
        label: '*Full Name',
        placeholder: 'Full Name',
        value: "$userData.name",
        validation: 'required'
      },
      {
        $formkit: 'submit',
        label: 'Save',
        disabled: '$get(form).state.valid !== true'
      }
    ]
  }
]
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this isn't a problem or issue with `FormKit` nor `FormKitSchema`. It's an issue with using `await` inside Vue's `reactive()` function.

In order to use a promise resolution value (i.e. `userData: await getData()`) in the initial `reactive()` argument object of a component (like in the `formComponent.vue` example), the calling/parent component must wrap them in a `<Suspense>` tag. Otherwise, Vue appears to simply not render the component at all, which is why there were no errors and nothing showed up.

From the Vue.js docs on [Suspense](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html)...
`A component with async setup() must be nested in a <Suspense> in order to be rendered.`

Therefore, the `formComponent.vue` code in the question is okay. Just needed to add a `<Suspense>` tag to the template anywhere the `<FormComponent>` is used. For example...

Example: `parentView.vue`

```
<Suspense>
  <FormComponent/>
</Suspense>
```

NOTE: As of this writing, the `<Suspense>` element is experimental and may change.

Comment: your code seems working thanks, but there is another issue. after saving form resets itself, changes goes back to original state. but after refreshing page, data comes from backend. how could this be solved? @A-Diddy

Comment: After making a few forms with Formkit, I dont recall that issue. It can be tricky modifying Formkit values after init... I would recommend avoiding it if possible.

Comment: it was my mistake after sending a post request. solved it. thanks.